# Making Excel jump to a Row

Tags: excel

This should be simple, but I can't seem to find the answer!

I use an Excel spreadsheet for product pricing, weight, and description. I want to type a part number into "X1" and I would like for Excel to locate the part number in column "F" and go to the Row that that part number is located in. I have used =14 + MATCH(X1,F15:F1835,0) to find the Row but then I have to manually go to the Row to see all the information about that part. I would like for Excel to automatically jump to the Row.

Comment: You will need vba in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: just as a side note: your formula can be reduced to `=MATCH(X1,F:F,0)`

Comment: I would set this up to populate the cells next to where you type the part number with the information about that part. Then, no VBA is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It goes in the Worksheet Object module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rFound As Range

With ActiveSheet
    If Not Intersect(.Range("X1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Set rFound = .Columns(6).Find(What:=Target, After:=.Cells(1, 6), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto rFound, True
        Else
            MsgBox Range("X1").Value & " was not found!"
        End If        
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

`Target` is the value in `Range("X1")`. Only the change made in that cell will be looked for in column F. If you have more than one of that value in column F it will only find the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem but on a shared excel sheet, so no VBA possible.

there is a way using the [Name Manager] on the [Formula] tab and than a shape from the [insert] tab

1. select an random area on your sheet and than
2. click on the [Name Manager] on the Formula tab,
3. select [New...]
4. type in a random name (i used JUMP) and click [OK] and [Close]
5. go to [Insert] tab click [Shapes] and create a shape of your choice (i used a text box that looks like a normal button)
6. then right click the shape and select [hyperlink...]
7. click [Place in This Document] and select under [Defined Names] on the right side the JUMP label that you just created and press [OK]
8. now go back to the [Name Manager] on the [Formulas] tab and select your name tag (JUMP)
   on the bottom of the name manager window is a code line called [Refers to:]
9. type the following formula into this field (Note: instead of Sheet1 you need to enter the name of your sheet)
   =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(Sheet1!$X$1,Sheet1!$F:$F,0),6,1,1,"Sheet1"))
10. click [close] and confirm the change

now you will always jump to the line that has the part number typed in cell X1 when you click on the shape.

it was the only way i could make dynamic hyperlinks on excel without VBA,
(the whole thing is a bit glitchy though, you have to use the exact sequence of steps described above or you will not be able to see the name tag when creating the hyperlink, but once its done it works like a charm :)

Works in excel 2010

Greetings from Germany
T.